# Choose sections to hide when exporting developer story to PDF

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

Currently in SO Jobs, I can choose what parts of the CV I want to keep when exporting it to PDF. However in the developer story, clicking on the PDF button directly generates a PDF file without letting me alter it before.

Is this intentional? Can we get back the same functionality as SO jobs? I would like it for two reasons:

- I want to highlight different experiences depending on the employer I am targeting
- There are some sections that I'd prefer to always hide, so as not to clutter the CV (e.g. books I've read)

Comment: Bump.  I wish I could add a bounty.  This is essential functionality and I'm terribly disappointed to see it gone.

Comment: Yeah, same here. =/
It was a killer feature.