# PDF Export lacks essential customizations

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

With the Developer Story seemingly out of private beta, I think it's worth posting a newer version of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321412/choose-sections-to-hide-when-exporting-developer-story-to-pdf).

The [original post regarding the developer story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/introducing-the-developer-story?rq=1) contained this:

> **Will I still be able to export to PDF?**
>
> Yes, this feature will continue to work with the new developer story.

That appears to not be the case.  PDF exports were customizable with Careers, if [poorly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127130/careers-change-order-of-sections-in-pdf-export) [so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268184/careers-pdf-export-github-entry-titles).  Now they're not at all.

Are there plans to rectify this?  I feel like months and months were spent developing something that's less useful than what came before.  I'm sorry to be harsh; I know a lot of extremely talented developers (more talented than me) spent a lot of time on this.  But getting a PDF to a recruiter is a pretty ubiquitous, non-negotiable requirement for a *huge* number of developers.  I hope this gets fixed.

Comment: Came here to request the same feature. I at least need the ability to hide sections in the PDF again, like I could with the old résumé. Run-of-the-mill employers don't care to see my technological likes/dislikes, nor my favorite blog posts and books, on my résumé.

Comment: Short term workaround-inspect the seconds you wish to remove and delete their nodes, then print the website to pdf.

Comment: Jesus - I hope that's not the official position of SE. Keeping the old careers export around as needed, until this is fixed, would be an acceptable workaround. Trying to print a webpage to PDF - not so much.

Comment: It'll take a little bit to prioritize, but we're looking at all of this - absolutely. Don't think we're ignoring it, just addressing the critical stuff first and moving down the list.

Comment: Awesome - much thanks, @Nick.  Is the old PDF export available anywhere still? I'm fortunately not looking for a new job, but I imagine there's at least a few who are, and might *need* a quality PDF CV _now_.

Comment: @NickCraver Thanks for hearing us!

Comment: @Will does that work for you? I still can't print even after deleting the nodes. =/

Comment: Well, the nodes don't prevent you from printing, so that's a different problem.

Comment: @NickCraver Can you provide any more information at this time? Has this issue been discussed and prioritized with the development team yet?

Comment: @Will I tried both hiding the nodes and deleting the nodes I did not want to appear on my PDF before clicking the PDF button. The sections still appeared in the generated PDF, for me, in Chrome.

Comment: @gotgenes you have to print the website within your browser, not use their print button.

Comment: @NickCraver I am sorry but without the ability to print (which needs the ability to select portions of the story). The developer site becomes useless. The one **MUST HAVE** options is to generate a printed version of the resume so it can be shared. Not all employers are as enlightened as SO. PS. The original version was great (why did we lose that functionality).

Comment: @Nick - any movement on this at all?  It's close to 4 months since your last comment - is there any way to at least get the same customizable pdf export the old careers site had?  Something for this to at least be usable for any candidate who needs a PDF of their resume (which I think is significantly more than the folks in the NY office think)

Comment: @NickCraver Please, I beg the team to add back the ability to trim sections out of the generated PDF.

Comment: @gotgenes I imagine this feature, for whatever reason, isn't high on NY's priority list - I imagine more revenue can be grabbed elsewhere. Recommend you check out other services where YOU'RE the paying customer - https://www.visualcv.com/  See other recommendations here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39369/software-to-manage-ones-resume/39401#39401

Comment: From the SO Careers' Stakeholder's perspective, I can wholly understand why removing the "export to PDF" was removed. Making it simple for users to circumvent the SO Careers marketplace is detrimental to their bottom line. Understandable.

Comment: @NickCraver Also please consider this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362961/why-cant-i-add-a-custom-section-in-developer-story.

Comment: I removed the [status-review] tag from this post because the Jobs product no longer exists.