# Why can't I add a custom section in developer story?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, developer-story

What is the reasoning behind that I can't add a custom section on developer story?

Surely it would enhance the number of features developer story has. And it would potentially do more good than harm (as people who don't want custom sections wouldn't use it). What are the reasons one can't do it?

For example, with a custom section I mean the user could create a section with any title (e.g. "technical summary"), and it could have a single text area where the user could type in anything he/she likes (e.g. in case of "technical summary" it could have "C,C++, etc").

Comment: custom section for example?

Comment: @SurajRao Example would be title "Technology Summary", content: "C,C++,.."

Comment: Does "Milestone" not cover your use case?

Comment: "Milestone" doesn't cover that it has mandatory requirement for date which is odd for a section like "Technical summary". Also what you put under "Milestone" goes under "Other" section, which is not reasonable for "Technical Summary" , since for devs that section should not go as "Other" as it is important part of CV.

Comment: Would the "personal statement" section suffice for a technical summary?

Comment: Milestone would be the best section here. You can add any category to a milestone item such as "technical summary".

Comment: @Kit Yes but Milestone has requirement for specifying dates, which is odd for technical skills isn't it?

Comment: @Des "personal statement" does seem like the closest you can get to having a technical summary section. Although separate section would still be better.

Comment: @Des btw. no way to specify phone number?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava thanks for the feedback. You can add your phone number on your job preferences. Its not publicly displayed on Developer Story but when you express interest in a company, then your contact information is shared with that company.

Comment: @Des Yes but you are missing point when people may use developer profile feature to generate a PDF out of it, and there they'd need phone number? (ps. Also, I feel like asking a question similar to above question, because I feel comments don't address it properly...).

Answer (score 1):

One reason could be, if you want to funnel certain data types/values into specific fields at the database levels.

Giving people the option to "free-text it", would mean, from a data-analysis point of view, StackExchange would need to do a possible substantial amount of more work to provide you (a custom field) user with relevant jobs, advertising, etc.

E.G: I could, with this suggested power, setup my whole Developer Story with custom sections, and therefor not gain all of the benefits that was obviously intended with Developer Story. I've personally encountered this (or lack of) on previous data migration projects, where I just wished I could travel back in time and ask the initial devs to please categorize the data just a little better and not give the end users as much free-form input fields.

While I do realize we have a pretty savvy community vs what I'd call a non-technical user base. Meaning, the problem I illustrated above, MIGHT be less of a concern. It ultimately does open a wormhole of sorts for data which will need some TLC to be converted into something useful (should SO want to do so)

Answer (score -1):

Milestone items act as custom sections as they allow you to define your own category.

For example:
[image]