# Can I hide Developer Story entries in the CV View?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, cv-export

I am happy to show many of my personal projects in my Developer Story, but when I export the CV, I would really prefer that only the "professional" ones are listed.  How can I hide or reorder events when saving as PDF?

Comment: this seems to be a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336048/pdf-export-lacks-essential-customizations, which unfortunately doesn't have an answer. sounds like SO isn't really that motivated to provide a decent way to present resumes.

Comment: the PDF generator of cv lacks lot of customization or flexibility

Comment: What I did was put developer story in traditional view, saved to disk, then edited the html file, added some page breaks, then printed to pdf. Looks a lot nicer that way.